# ¿Como cambiar el tamaño de los iconos de un Bottom Navigation View en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

veréis, tengo un Bottom Navigation View al cual le he añadido la propiedad para que no aparezcan las etiquetas de texto, pero los iconos en la barra salen muy pequeños, me gustaría hacerlos algo más grandes, pero no se como hacerlo o si existe una propiedad para ello, a ver si me podéis echar una mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me respondo a mi mismo: con la versión `28.0.0` de la support library se añadió un atributo que es: `app:itemIconSize="tamaño deseado"` que te lo cambia. Espero que le sirva a alguién.